# Shift elements to right in a array to add a new element in java

Tags: java, arrays

Im trying to shift some elements of the array to get space for a new element in the index chosen, but my array is cloning the element after the index till the end of the array

```
public void insertAtRank(int r, Object o) {
    for(int i = r+1 ; i < arrayVetor.length; i++ ){
        arrayVetor[i] = arrayVetor[i-1];
    }
    this.arrayVetor[r] = o;
}
```

```
arrayVetor.insertAtRank(0, "1");
arrayVetor.insertAtRank(1, "2");
arrayVetor.insertAtRank(2, "3");
arrayVetor.insertAtRank(3, "4");
arrayVetor.insertAtRank(2, "5");
```

the output:
`[1, 2, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]`

what i want:
`[1, 2, 5, 3, 4, null, null, null, null, null]`

Answer (score 1):

Think about what happens in that loop for, say, `r == 0`:

- The element at `arrayVetor[0]` is copied to `arrayVetor[1]`
- The element at `arrayVetor[1]` is copied to `arrayVetor[2]`
- The element at `arrayVetor[2]` is copied to `arrayVetor[3]`
- ...
- The element at `arrayVetor[8]` is copied to `arrayVetor[9]`.

So you end up copying (well, assigning) the value at `arrayVetor[0]` to all elements in the array.

What you actually want to be doing is:

- Copying the element at `arrayVetor[8]` to `arrayVetor[9]`
- Copying the element at `arrayVetor[7]` to `arrayVetor[8]`
- Copying the element at `arrayVetor[6]` to `arrayVetor[7]`
- ...
- Copying the element at `arrayVetor[0]` to `arrayVetor[1]`

And then assigning the new value to `arrayVetor[0]`.

Comment: I think I don't know how to do this in terms of code, but I understand how it should work.

Comment: Hint: you don't always have to use `i++` as the update in the for loop.

Comment: ```public void insertAtRank(int r, Object o) {
        if (arrayVetor[r] != null) {
            for (int i = r + 1; i >= r; i--) {
                arrayVetor[i+1] = arrayVetor[i];
            }
        }
        this.arrayVetor[r] = o;
    }```

Comment: I created this code, following your instructions, but for example, when I have an array of size 10 and I place a element at index "7" and another at index "9":
`[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 7, null, 9]`
when I do an "arrayVetor.insertAtRank(7, "7.5");"
its supposed to happen:
`[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 7.5, 7, 9]`
but what is happening is:
`[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 7.5, 7, null]`